# My Java book shows two of the same objects being created, yet they fail the Object.equals() call. Why?

Tags: java, object, equals

```
class Test{
  public static void main (String [] args){
    Test t1 = new Test();
    Test t2 = new Test();
    if(!t1.equals(t2))
      System.out.println("they're not equal");
  }
}
```

And it says it will print the string... why are they not equal? Do they need to be the exact same object in memory to pass that call? It must then be different than simply comparing all of the object attribute values because I would assume they would be the same (unless there is some time based attribute?). Anyone care to elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't override the `equals(..)` method, then yes - they need to be the exact same object in memory. That's because the default implementation of `equals(..)` provided by the `Object` class (which all classes extend by default) uses the (sort-of) memory address of the object (it uses `==` comparison on the instances)

But if you want to make them equal based on their fields, then override `equals(..)` and provide the custom logic. Note that you should also implement `hashCode(..)` in this case. Refer to the [`java.lang.Object#equals(..)` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)